# How can I stop the category axis overlapping my kendo chart?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

[image: Category axis overlaps]

Please can you tell me how to stop the category axis overlapping? It has this problem in Chrome but not Internet Explorer. Sometimes when I refresh in Chrome, it works as expected - it does not overlap.

I've tried setting axiscrossingvalue to various values, but it does not help.

Here's my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart()
.Name("sales_count")
.Title("Sales Count: " + Model.SalesCount_Total[0])
.Legend(legend => legend
    .Visible(false)
)
.ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
    .Background("transparent")
    .Height(graphHeight)
)
.Series(series =>
{
    series
    .Column(Model.SalesCount_Values[0]).Name("Total Sales")
    .Color(Model.Colors[2]).Opacity(1);
})
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis
    .Categories(Model.SalesCount_Categories[0])
    .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
    .Labels(label => label.Rotation(270))
)
.ValueAxis(axis => axis
                .Numeric("Value")
                .Min(0)
)
.Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
    .Visible(true)
     .Template("#= category #: #= value#"))
)
```

Comment: Could you try .Rotation(-90). It is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried -90 rotation and got the same problem. Sometimes when I refresh it it looks fine, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that giving the label a margin stops it overlapping the chart data.

```
    .Labels(label => label.Rotation(270).Margin(15))
```